# Specify container name using testcontainers in Scala

Tags: scala, testcontainers

Using dimafeng's [test containers for Scala](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala/) I can create several containers from the same image:

```scala
class TestWithTwoDatabases extends FunSuite with ForEachTestContainer  {
  protected val inputContainer: PostgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:13.3")
  protected val outputContainer: PostgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:13.3")
  override val container: MultipleContainers = MultipleContainers(inputContainer, outputContainer)

  // Some integration tests
}
```

How distinguish them within the docker console? I currently have:

```sh
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          NAMES
a2bee9488c02   postgres:13.3  youthful_archimedes # I'd like to have inputContainer here
2c645ed1c54c   postgres:13.3  agitated_cori       # I'd like to have outputContainer here
```

How can I specify the containers' names when creating them in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it. And it is not clear why you need it.

The idea of test containers is that you'd use them in your code and you can distinguish them by reference, `inputContainer` and `outputContainer` in your case. It is not designed to be used in a form of a booting framework, like `docker compose`, so you can use it externally outside of your code.

Also setting a fixed name to the container will make it impossible to run tests that claim same container name in CI environment with shared docker engine.

Comment: I wanted it for debugging purposes. But I indeed forgot to think about the CI environment. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll find another way to debug my code.

Comment: Making use of networks and network aliases might be a workaround for you, but the use case is still unclear to me.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to put a breaking point in the code then open a shell in the container and see what's been written in postgres

Comment: You can get container id from debug session. They have methods getContainerName/id